# WiFi Disabled in Bullseye After Long Idle

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I have an RPI 2B with an RT5370 WiFi dongle running Bullseye. I'm not sure the interval, but if my device sits idle for a number of hours, the WiFi gets disabled. I can use the mouse and click on the WiFi icon and restart it but I need it to remain live. I didn't have this problem before Bullseye.

I've Googled quite a bit to find out how to disable power management on WiFi and the USB ports but haven't found anything. Can someone point me in the right direction?

BTW, I think it *might* be the USB ports that are getting turned off. When I plugged in my keyboard and mouse to deal with the problem, the mouse didn't power up for a bit.

Comment: `iwconfig wlan0 power off` - substitute you wifi device for `wlan0`

Comment: by the way `it might be the USB ports that are getting turned off` is highly unlikely - while at least with some Pi's it is possible, you'd have to write specific code to do so

Answer (score 0):

> `iwconfig wlan0 power off` - substitute you wifi device for `wlan0`

It looks like power management is already off but I'll try it anyway.

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Is this thing on?"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: 60:32:B1:FA:48:F2   
      Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:35  Invalid misc:5671   Missed beacon:0
```